# Transforming Wide dataset to long format with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
Name   County    Industry   Jobs.2019  Jobs.2018  Establish.2019  Establish.2018  EPW.2019  EPW.2018
rows_0 Adams, OH Auto        1         2          3               4               5         6
row_1  Allen, OH Mfg         2         3          5               7               9         10
...
row_100 Adams,OH IT          5         32         1               87              8         9
```

Ultimately, I would like to transform in a long format such as:

```
Name   County    Industry  Jobs Establish EPW Year
rows_0 Adams, OH Auto        1    3         5   2019
rows_1 Adams, OH Auto        2    4         6   2018
rows_2 Allen, OH Mfg         1    5         9   2019
```

I was able to get it into long format with melt:

```
data_df_unpivot = data_df.melt(id_vars=['County', 'Industry'], var_name=['metric'], value_name='value')
```

but that really only gets me the format:

```
County    Industry metric    value
Adams, OH  Auto    Jobs.2019 1
Adams, OH  Auto    Jobs.2018 2
Adams, OH  Auto    EPW.2019  5
Adams, OH  Auto    EPW.2018  6
```

I know I need to do a split on Jobs.2019, etc. but not sure what to do after the fact to get it into the appropriate format.

All the data is coming from an API and is nested JSON that I had to flatten. The end goal is to load into SQL so I'm wondering if I do the ETL in Python or let Snowflake handle, either way I'm faced with the same issue with elongating the table.

This will also be a living table as data comes out i.e Jobs.2020, Jobs.2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your title: use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html).

```
print (pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=["Jobs","Establish","EPW"],
                       i=["Name","County","Industry"],
                       j="Year", sep=".", suffix="\d+")
       .reset_index())

      Name     County Industry  Year  Jobs  Establish  EPW
0    row_0  Adams, OH     Auto  2019     1          3    5
1    row_0  Adams, OH     Auto  2018     2          4    6
2    row_1  Allen, OH      Mfg  2019     2          5    9
3    row_1  Allen, OH      Mfg  2018     3          7   10
4  row_100  Adams, OH       IT  2019     5          1    8
5  row_100  Adams, OH       IT  2018    32         87    9
```

Comment: I either need to get better at searching or reading documentation. 
Thank you for accommodating my denseness